# launch a script which requires to be launched from a specific path via crontab

Tags: scripting, cron, pwd

I have a script which before being launched checks via pwd if the path upon launch is something specific (say dir/subdir/script)

```
current_folder=$(pwd | grep dir/subdir/script)
if [ "$current_folder" == "" ]; then
{
echo "something bad"
exit
}
fi
```

how can this script be launched via crontab? I cannot remove the check with pwd or amend the script content under any circumstance since it's subject to continuous updates that would be replaced

Thanks everyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify several commands, separated by `;` or `&&`, as your
cron job, for example:

```
* * * * * cd /some/path && foo
```

(This will only run `foo` if the `cd` was successful.)

Comment: that was what I tried which didn't work at first since in the line I had to add some % chars which then came out need to be escaped when used on a crontab line. Thanks for your help, you were right btw